# SSL Connection With Private Keys in HSM

Tags: java, openssl, netty, pkcs#11, hsm

I would like to implement a ssl connection which the RSA key pair are kept in the Hardware Security Module (HSM) in Java.

By using openssl pkcs11 engine, I achieved the TLS connection with the following engine configuration.

```
[openssl_def]
engines = engine_section

[engine_section]
pkcs11 = pkcs11_section

[pkcs11_section]
engine_id = pkcs11
MODULE_PATH = /home/ubuntu/Desktop/vendorlib.so
PIN = "123456"
init = 0

[req]
distinguished_name = test_name
[req_distinguished_name]
```

and then I create a certificate using this engine with the following command where ssl_key is kept in HSM device.

```
OPENSSL_CONF=engine.conf openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -subj '/CN=test/' -sha256 -config engine.conf -engine pkcs11 -keyform engine -key slot_2-label_ssl_key -out cert.pem
```

I can confirm the certificate and key pair with the following openssl server and client commands.

For the server:

```
OPENSSL_CONF=engine.conf openssl s_server -engine pkcs11 -keyform engine -key slot_2-label_ssl_key -cert cert.pem -accept 44330
```

For the client:

```
OPENSSL_CONF=engine.conf openssl s_client -connect localhost:44330 -engine pkcs11
```

However, I need this connection to be established in Vertx(3.81) Java 8 connection.

When I look at the documentation of the vertx, there is an OpenSSLEngineOptions which can be set as serverOptions but I couldn't figure where to put parameters such as key name, slot number and engine id etc. 
In fact, [OpenSSLEngineOptions](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/net/OpenSSLEngineOptions.html) has a constructor which takes JsonObject, but I couldn't find any sample for this JsonObject.

Here is a code snipped where I instantiate the Vertx ssl option

```
HttpServerOptions serverOptions = jerseyServerOptions.getServerOptions();
OpenSSLEngineOptions openSSLOptions = new OpenSSLEngineOptions();
serverOptions.setOpenSslEngineOptions(openSSLOptions);
serverOptions.setPort(1234);
serverOptions.setSsl(true);

String certCopy = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
PemKeyCertOptions pemKeyCertOptions = new PemKeyCertOptions().setCertValue(Buffer.buffer(certValue));
serverOptions.setPemKeyCertOptions(pemKeyCertOptions);
```

**TLDR;**
How can we establish a SSL connection in Vertx where the private key stored in only HSM and could't be extracted?

Edit:
I found the parser of the jsonObject in the constructor of OpenSSLEngineOptions [here](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/generated/io/vertx/core/net/OpenSSLEngineOptionsConverter.java). Unfortunately, it only reads the sessionCacheEnabled option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution using Security Provider and Java Keystore. Here is the sample code:

```
/*
pkcs11.cfg example:
name=PKCS11
library=vendor provided library absolute path
slot=0
*/
String propertyPath = "/root/IdeaProjects/ssl/pkcs11.cfg;
char[] pin = "1234".toCharArray();
Provider p = new SunPKCS11(propertyPath);
Security.removeProvider("IAIK");
Security.addProvider(p);
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11",p);
ks.load(null,pin);
```

After the initialization of KeyStore, you can direct your SSLContext to KeyStore. But according to [Java 8 PKCS11 Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html#KeyStoreRestrictions), the CKA_ID attribute of the certificate and the private key should match. If pkcs11 engine matches the pair of certificate and key, it should demonstrate as alias.

```
//Showing aliases
Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
for (; aliases.hasMoreElements(); ){
   System.out.println(aliases.nextElement());
}
```

After verifying aliases, we'll use SSLContext to bind our KeyManager.

```
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstane("TLS");
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyManagerFactory.init(ks,pin);
ctx.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
```